# Unable to create converter for class

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь создать базу из получаемых данных JSON

```
const val CURRENT_USER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_user")
data class User_new(
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    val avatar: String,
    @SerializedName("balance")
    val balance: Double,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id_user: Int,
    @SerializedName("login")
    val login: String,
    @SerializedName("not_adult")
    val notAdult: Int,
    @SerializedName("token")
    val token: String
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = CURRENT_USER_ID
}
```

data class используется здесь

```
   data class authClient(
    @SerializedName("msg")
    val msg: String,
    @SerializedName("response")
       val user: User_new,
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: String
)
```

Создание базы

```
@Dao
interface CurrentUserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upset(weatherEntry: User_new)

    @Query("select * from current_user where id = $CURRENT_USER_ID")
    fun getGlavsMetric(): LiveData<ImperialCurrentUserEntry>
}
```

ImperialCurrentUserEntry

```
data class ImperialCurrentUserEntry(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "avatar")
    override val avata_user: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "balance")
    override val balance_user: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_user")
    override val id_user_a: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "login")
    override val login_user: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "notAdult")
    override val notAdult_user: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "token")
    override val token_user: String
):UnitSpecificCurrentUser
```

ForecastDatabase

```
@Database(
    entities = [User_new::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class ForecastDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentGlavsDao():CurrentUserDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: ForecastDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK){
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it}
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context)=
                Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                    ForecastDatabase::class.java, "forecast.db")
                    .build()
    }
}
```

Вызываю так

```
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val textcurrent = apiServer
            .getAuth("Login","Pass").await()

        textView.text = textcurrent.user.toString()
    }
```

Ошибка появляется после запуска программы и получения ссылки
[image: Ошибка]

Ругается на этот код

```
val textcurrent = apiServer
            .getAuth("Login","Pass").await()
```

Извиняюсь за много текст, прошу помощи

Comment: Разберитесь с `id` у `User_new` - у Вас одно поле помечено аннотацией с именем `id`, и ещё одно так называется. `Gson` не может определить в какое писать. Если это поле обязательное и переименовать его нельзя, можете дополнительно пометить его аннотацией с фейковым именем - тогда конвертер схавает. Хотя я что-то не понимаю - зачем писать в базу константный `0` да ещё и в качестве первичного ключа?

Comment: @woesss а как бы вы поступили с первичным ключем ?

Comment: @woesss
UPD: можете создать ответ ? Вы были правы.Я помечу его решением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в названии `var Id`

```
const val CURRENT_USER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_user")
data class User_new(
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    val avatar: String,
    @SerializedName("balance")
    val balance: Double,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id_user: Int,
    @SerializedName("login")
    val login: String,
    @SerializedName("not_adult")
    val notAdult: Int,
    @SerializedName("token")
    val token: String
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = CURRENT_USER_ID
}
```

Так как анотация уже имеет название `id`

```
@SerializedName("id")
val id_user: Int,
```

Нужно просто заменить название `var id` на var `id_currect`